# My react router does not work on some routes

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react. In my index.js file, I have following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';
import Users from './components/Users.jsx';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render((
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
        </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The first route which is

```
<Route path="/" component={App} />
```

works, but the second route

```
<Route path="/users" component={Users} />
```

does not work. And I got the **'Cannot GET /users'** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that the route is not handled on the server side.

You can do something like the following on your server:

```
app.get('*', function (request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest you to do is to have one parent Layout Component and then have your routes as child routes of that parent component

Say your parent component is like

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now you can have your routes like

```
import Users from './components/Users.jsx';
import Layout from './components/Layout.jsx';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render((
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Layout} >
               <IndexRoute component={App}/>
               <Route path="/users" component={Users} />

        </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Also since you are using `browserHistory` and if you try to directly access it with the url you will get an error

In order to solve this in your webpack `webpack` add `historyApiFallback: true`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I need to add historyApiFallback when I start the server, just like the instruction from react-router: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls

Comment: Yes  you will need it, you need it with browserHistory but not with hashHistory. However I will recommend to add a parent route